# Overflow:scroll in horizontal direction is not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I creating a website where the website have several `<div>` in the body where all the `<div>` is fixed on its position but only `<div class = "content">` can be scroll.

This is my HTML structure for my Master.Page;

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="navLeft">

    </div>
    <div class="navTop">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphNavTop" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphBanner" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphDivider" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphContent" runat="server">
            (there are several another <div> here for content pages)
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is my CSS code;

```
body 
{
    margin:auto;
    width:1280px;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
}

form
{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}

.navLeft
{
    width:60px;
    min-height:100vh;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    border-right:1px solid rgb(0,177,169);
}

.navTop
{
    min-width:550px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

.banner
{
    min-width:1200px;
    height:75px;
    background-color:rgb(235,235,235);
}

.divider
{
    min-width:800px;
    height:24px;
    background-color:rgb(0,177,169);
}

.content
{
    width:auto;
    height:470px;
}
```

Before I make any changes to my CSS code, my website look like this;

[image]

Noted that I have another table where I want to put it like this;

[image]

When I put overflow into .content, like this;

```
.content
{
    overflow:scroll;
    width:auto;
    height:470px;
}
```

The horizaontal scroll is not functional, thus make my website look like this as result;

[image]

All the `<div>` in my Master.Page is fixed on it position except for `<div class="content">` where it have its own scrollbar. However no matter what I try i can seem to make it look like second image where the table is side y side and my horizontal scrollbar is disable.

Is there something missing in my CSS code or my CSS code have some error that I not aware of?

I hope my problem is understandable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which width? body width? form width? or .content width? because if specified width for body it will give white space if open on different monitor resolution. I try to play around with .content width but it still give the same result

Answer (score 0):

The table on the right doesn't fit the window, so that it goes down below the first table. You should recalculate the width of both tables so that they could fit together in single row.

If you want your content to scroll on horizon, you should define numbered width. Not using auto property.

Comment: as far as i manage to calculate the width, the table left is 726px, white space 10px and table right is 577px. I try to change the .content width to 1315px but it still give the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you:

```
.content
{
    overflow:scroll;
    height:470px;
}

.content > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The attribute `display: inline-block;` should work if it is also applied to the tables (since they are block elements by default).